# Feature Preview in SolidWorks

Tags: vb.net, solidworks

I am working on a simulation application that uses SolidWorks geometry data to locate components that aren't part of the part or assembly, and will never be.

However, as the user selects the references that will locate these items, I would like my application to "fake in" the components that my application creates, in much the same way as SolidWorks performs a feature preview.

Imagine that there's a model of a box in SolidWorks, and my application will show how cans will fit into the box.  I'd like to be able to draw a preview of the cans without actually adding cylindrical features or can components.  See the image for a better idea of what I'm looking for.  In the image, I created a feature and took a screen shot of the feature preview for a linear pattern.  My application wouldn't have the original can in the corner.

[image: Screenshot of feature preview I'm describing...]

How is this done, does anyone have any pointers?

Thanks,
SH